# Joining multiple tables with a single query

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

### Student

```
student_id  FirstName   LastName
---------------------------------------------------
1           Joe         Bloggs
2           Alan        Day
3           David       Johnson
```

### Student_Course

```
course_id   student_id  courseName
---------------------------------------------------             
1           1           Computer Science
2           1           David Beckham Studies
3           1           Geography   
1           3           Computer Science
3           3           Geography
```

### Student_clubs

```
club_id student_id  club_name               club_count
---------------------------------------------------
1       1           Footbal                     10
2       1           Rugby                       10
3       1           Syncronized Swimming        10
4       3           Tennis                      15
```

In the above example, student with id = 1 takes 3 course and is part of 3 clubs.
If i was to find out which courses a student is involved in or which club the student is part of i can do it but i will need to run two queries. Is it possible to run a single query against the 
tables listed above so that the results come out like this:

### Output

```
student_id      FirstName       Student_associated_courses          Student_associated_clubs 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               Joe             1,2,3                               Football, Rugby, Syncronized swimming
3               David           1,3                                 Tennis
```

Is it possible to get the above output with just one query? I am using JDBC to get the data so i am trying to see if i can avoid multiple trips to get the necessary data.

Comment: MySQl is about as far from Oracle as it is possible to get while still pretending to be a database. Pick one. Then say what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `DISTINCT` in `MySQL`

```
SELECT  a.student_ID, a.firstname,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.course_ID),
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  c.club_name)
FROM    student a
        INNER JOIN student_Course b
            ON a.student_id = b.student_ID
        INNER JOIN student_clubs c
            ON a.student_ID = c.student_ID
GROUP BY    a.student_ID, a.firstname
```

- [**See SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47f20/2)

Comment: Is there an equivalent method for Oracle?

Comment: @ziggy [LISTAGG or WM_CONCAT](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student s JOIN
(SELECT sc."student_id", listagg(sc."course_id", ',')within group(ORDER BY sc."course_id")
FROM Student_Course sc
GROUP BY sc."student_id") s_course ON s."student_id"=s_course."student_id"
JOIN (SELECT sl."student_id", listagg(sl."club_name", ',')within GROUP(ORDER BY sl."club_name")
     FROM Student_clubs sl
     GROUP BY sl."student_id") s_club ON s."student_id"=s_club."student_id"
```

The "catch" is that LISTAGG doesn't work with DISTINCT keyword

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69e9b/19) is a fiddle